# Tuning ranking in search result

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
doc1 = {"id":1,"text":"tonight"}
doc2 = {"id":2,"text":"tonight tonight"}
doc3 = {"id":3,"text":"tonight tonight tonight"}
doc4 = {"id":4,"text":"tonight and something else"}
doc5 = {"id":5,"text":"tonight and you"}

es.index(index="tonight", document=doc1)
es.index(index="tonight", document=doc2)
es.index(index="tonight", document=doc3)
es.index(index="tonight", document=doc4)
es.index(index="tonight", document=doc5)
```

Suppose I have the above documents indexed. When I use the below query:

```
data = json.dumps({
    "query":{ 
        "bool":{
            "should":[
                {
                    "match":{
                        "text": "tonight"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

The hits returned in the order of `"tonight tonight tonight", "tonight tonight","tonight", "tonight and you" and "tonight and something else"`.

May I ask if there is a way to make `"tonight"` as the first hit returned with highest _score?

In my real life use case, I am conducting iterating throught the whole index to find out the most relevant text other than itself, and the document being searched should be returned as the first hit (most matched) if possible.

Could someone please give me some ideas on how to query?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Elasticsearch default index mapping, then you can use a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on the `text.keyword` field. Otherwise, you can add multi fields to the `text` field using [Update Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex).

The term query is used to return documents that match exactly with the search term.

You can include the `term` query in the bool should clause, which will increase the score of exact matching documents, as compared to the other documents' score.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "text": "tonight"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "text.keyword": "tonight"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Search Results will be

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 5,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.5025805,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stof",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.5025805,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "tonight"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.13236837,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "text": "tonight tonight tonight"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.12794474,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "text": "tonight tonight"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 0.08185939,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "text": "tonight and you"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0.07130444,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "text": "tonight and something else"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! What if I am not searching only a word "tonight" but a long sentence/text with 50+ or even 100+ characters? I need to find out the most relevant text other than itself in the es index. In this case I wouldnt be able to use "term.keyword" I guess?